# Getting a new line in the last cell of the CSV, How to eliminate it?

Tags: python, csv

My code: To split each line of CSV and save it to a separate CSV file

```
import csv          
with open("PMBC_Final_Neucube.csv") as data:
    for index, line in enumerate(data):
        with open('sam{}_diet.csv'.format(index), 'w', newline='') as fw:
            writer = csv.writer(fw, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
            writer.writerow(line.split(','))
```

The required output is shown in image 1 but I am getting output as Image 2

[image]

Comment: Does each output file only contain one row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use rstrip() function while writing the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be taking an input CSV file and writing each row to a separate numbered CSV file containing just that one row. A workaround to stop the final newline from being written would be to write the CSV row into a `StringIO` object, remove the newline and then write the resulting string to the output file as follows:

```
from io import StringIO        
import csv

with open('PMBC_Final_Neucube.csv') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)

    for index, line in enumerate(csv_input):
        with open('sam{}_diet.csv'.format(index), 'w', newline='') as f_output:
            row = StringIO(newline='')
            csv.writer(row).writerow(line)
            f_output.write(row.getvalue().rstrip())
```